# Wordpress URL rewrite with GET variables

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have tried to search a solution but was unable to find one. In my wordpress website i've got a custom page that retrieves data from the database. Now i have this url:

http://www.domain.com/party/?title=nameoftheparty&id=4

I need to rewrite it to:

http://www.domain.com/party/nameoftheparty/4/

I tried to add the rewrite url in .htaccess but i get an 404 page.

What do i need to do?

Comment: google wordpress + rewrite rule...

Comment: I tried, but it seems not to work for me.

Comment: well post the code you tried and then it may be possible to help you

Comment: Here are a few links to help you 1) http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/5413/need-help-with-add-rewrite-rule  2) http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/wordpress-url-rewrite/ , based on that try out something and ask for help if you get stuck.

Comment: @Anand: I have tried the solutions in the links, but i get nothing or redirected to the index.

Isn't there a simple solution? I thought someone would posted code by now.

Answer (score 3):

Add both the code snippets to functions.php

1.We are telling WordPress that `/party/nameoftheparty/4/` should be internally mapped to `/party/?title=nameoftheparty&id=4`

```
add_action( 'init', 'so27053217_init' );
function so27053217_init()
{
    add_rewrite_rule(
        '^party/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?',
        'index.php?pagename=party&title=$matches[1]&id=$matches[2]',
        'top' );    
}
```

This is optional and only required if you need to make use of `title` and `id` variables in your party page. They can be accessed using `get_query_var("title")`

```
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'so27053217_query_vars' );
function so27053217_query_vars( $query_vars )
{
    $query_vars[] = 'title';
    $query_vars[] = 'id';
    return $query_vars;
}
```

Remember to re-save your permalinks to flush rewrite rules.